# Angular Templates - inline expressions vs calling to function

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

Is there any difference between those two:

```
<li [ngClass]="{disabledField: condition1 && condition2 && condition3}">Click</li>
```

vs

```
<li [ngClass]="{disabledField: shouldDisableField()}">Click</li>
```

and in component class:

```
shouldDisableField(): boolean{
  return this.condition1 && this.condition2 && this.condition3;
}
```

Comment: No difference, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i9k8wo

Comment: The elegant and cleaner way would be, using a getter rather than a function `get shouldDisableField: boolean { return this.condition1 && this.condition2 && this.condition3 }` `<li [class.disabledField]="shouldDisableField">Click</li>`

Comment: is there anything unclear about [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080319/2545680)?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com Nope, very clear answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only difference is between a function call and evaluating an expression **in JavaScript**, Angular is irrelevant here. Function call is usually marginally slower, so the first option should be marginally faster.

Angular view compiler produces the following code for `updateRenderer` function:

```
function(_ck, _v) {
    var _co = _v.component;
---> var currVal_0 = _ck(_v, 3, 0, ((_co.condition1 && _co.condition2) && _co.condition3));
    _ck(_v, 2, 0, currVal_0);
}
```

And

```
function(_ck, _v) {
    var _co = _v.component;
--> var currVal_0 = _ck(_v, 3, 0, _co.shouldDisableField());
    _ck(_v, 2, 0, currVal_0);
}
```

As you can see only one line is different and that is all that matters.

You can read more about `updateRenderer` function in the article:

- [The mechanics of DOM updates in Angular](https://indepth.dev/posts/1129/the-mechanics-of-dom-updates-in-angular).

Comment: There's also human factor there: when it's refactored to a function inside the component, the developers are more likely to put more logic, extensive logic, or heavy logic there, just by accident, because they were looking into the component code, and were not looking how it's used in the template. Especially if someone marked the function as `private` (d'oh). Although putting some minor logic is fine, then extensive or heavy logic is very likely to kill the performance. And the effect grows/stacks with the lifetime of the source code, as such issues accumulate.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, yes, that's correct. If you need reusable logic, probably the best way is to put it into [a pure pipe](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-essential-difference-between-pure-and-impure-pipes-and-why-that-matters-999818aa068)

Answer (score 8):

Most answers here only mention the difference in performance as marginal.
I don't think this is correct and the performance here can be quiet significant.
Please refer to Phil Parsons great article about this: 
[Function calls in Angular expressions are killing your apps performance](http://spraso.com/functions-in-angular-expressions-are-killing-your-performance/)

You should be aware of the performance hit as shown there

Comment: There's also human factor there: when it's refactored to a function inside the component, the developers are more likely to put more logic, extensive logic, or heavy logic there, just by accident, because they were looking into the component code, and were not looking how it's used in the template. Especially if someone marked the function as `private` (d'oh). Although putting some minor logic is fine, then extensive or heavy logic is very likely to kill the performance. And the effect grows/stacks with the lifetime of the source code, as such issues accumulate.

Answer (score 3):

Not really, though I would suggest the second, as this is much cleaner and will help with minimising data transfer in templates.  Admittedly this may seem insignificant, but its good practice to compartmentalise javascript code, plus it will get the benefit of code minification AND gzip (if enabled on HTTP requests).

However, saying that, if this is an exception case, then the first may be more helpful with for other developers (or yourself) down the track, but I would only use this in a rare case, as the second gives you the ability to update/extend/fix it much easier, particularly if you're likely to re-use the same rule/condition.

With regards to Angular's binding model, I'm not sure if there is much in the way of caching (if that's what you were thinking) or performance that I've personally seen.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I was reffering more to caching (if exist) and performance issues. Would it just end up in a small overhead of using functions ?

Comment: comes down to stack space in the javascript engine, which in your case, not worth worrying about.  I have seen one case where I had some developers that ran a _for-loop_ on a table listing, adding a `click` Event Handler, where the function declaration was created each time, which killed the browser.   (e.g. `for(var index in tablerowbuttons) tablerowbuttons[index].onclick = function(evt) { ...some function... }`   decimated the stack space with thousands of function definitions)  Not sure how the V8 handles them now, but terrible practise never the less.

Comment: __side note__: If you ever need a function for each item due to scoping, I would suggest creating a common function with arguments of the scope data you need, then use the `function.bind` method.  (e.g. It's a tacky example, but gives the general idea..  `elm.onclick = handlerfunc.bind(elm, scopevar1, scopevar2, ...)`, and the `function handlerfunc(scopevar1, scopevar2, event) { ...`.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in above answers, both the approaches will work fine.

```
<li [ngClass]="{disabledField: condition1 && condition2 && condition3}">Click</li> 

<li [ngClass]="{disabledField: shouldDisableField()}">Click</li>
```

But there are some points which make them different.

One of the most important things is **AOT** strategy. Function calls may be a headache while migrating from **JIT** to **AOT** (which normally happens with most of the developers). If the called function is a private function, AOT Compilation throws a compile time error as it treats template and component as 2 different entities.

The other point is, data bindings are readable and can be understood easily.

Having said that, we may come across a situation, where data bindings alone wont solve the problem. Calling a function in those cases wouldn't be a wrong thing to do!

Hope this helps you! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a difference. I would use

```
<li [ngClass]="{disabledField: condition1 && condition2 && condition3}">Click</li>
```

if i'd only one expression like that in my template. Otherwise I'd use

```
<li [ngClass]="{disabledField: shouldDisableField()}">Click</li>
```

to reduce the written code.